# Android: Spinner setPadding not work

Tags: android, spinner

I use this code for set padding to spinner ( not for children )

```
Spinner spnCategory = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnCategory);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("UP");
list.add("Down");
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.dropdown_item);
spnCategory.setPadding(15, 5, 2, 4);
spnCategory.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

But this code not work

Comment: Try setting the padding in the xml layout of your spinner

Comment: I want set padding with codes

Comment: Okay I believe the issue is the view is being created within the onCreate then you are setting the padding after the view is created.  I will see if I can solve this issue through some test.

Comment: How ? can help me more ?

Comment: Set the padding to spnCategory.setPadding(100, 5, 2, 4); Let me know if it moves at all.

Comment: Okay so it didn't move at all?  Post your xml code for the layout

Comment: `dropdown_item.xml` please

Comment: This code create new spinner but i want use `spnCategory` style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing `dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.dropdown_item);`, it should work fine